# Numpy sum running length of non-zero values

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

Looking for a fast vectorized function that returns the rolling number of consecutive non-zero values. The count should start over at 0 whenever encountering a zero.  The result should have the same shape as the input array.

Given an array like this:

```
x = np.array([2.3, 1.2, 4.1 , 0.0, 0.0, 5.3, 0, 1.2, 3.1])
```

The function should return this:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post lists a vectorized approach which basically consists of two steps:

1. Initialize a zeros vector of the same size as input vector, x and set ones at places corresponding to non-zeros of `x`.
2. Next up, in that vector, we need to put minus of runlengths of each island right after the ending/stop positions for each "island". The intention is to use cumsum again later on, which would result in sequential numbers for the "islands" and zeros elsewhere.

**Here's the implementation -**

```
import numpy as np

#Append zeros at the start and end of input array, x
xa = np.hstack([[0],x,[0]])

# Get an array of ones and zeros, with ones for nonzeros of x and zeros elsewhere
xa1 =(xa!=0)+0

# Find consecutive differences on xa1
xadf = np.diff(xa1)

# Find start and stop+1 indices and thus the lengths of "islands" of non-zeros
starts = np.where(xadf==1)[0]
stops_p1 = np.where(xadf==-1)[0]
lens = stops_p1 - starts

# Mark indices where "minus ones" are to be put for applying cumsum
put_m1 = stops_p1[[stops_p1 < x.size]]

# Setup vector with ones for nonzero x's, "minus lens" at stops +1 & zeros elsewhere
vec = xa1[1:-1] # Note: this will change xa1, but it's okay as not needed anymore
vec[put_m1] = -lens[0:put_m1.size]

# Perform cumsum to get the desired output
out = vec.cumsum()
```

**Sample run -**

```
In [116]: x
Out[116]: array([ 0. ,  2.3,  1.2,  4.1,  0. ,  0. ,  5.3,  0. ,  1.2,  3.1,  0. ])

In [117]: out
Out[117]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32)
```

**Runtime tests -**

Here's some runtimes tests comparing the proposed approach against the other [`itertools.groupby based approach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29873173/3293881) -

```
In [21]: N = 1000000
    ...: x = np.random.rand(1,N)
    ...: x[x>0.5] = 0.0
    ...: x = x.ravel()
    ...: 

In [19]: %timeit sumrunlen_vectorized(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.9 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit sumrunlen_loopy(x)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.86 s per loop
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but could not determine how to calculate the negative run-lengths at the transition points.  Thanks for the solution.  It can be shortened it a bit by removing vec1, since vec1.cumsum() is equal to (x != 0) + 0.  I'm new here.  not sure if it is okay to edit someone else's answer.

Comment: @steve Ah yes good observation there! Let me edit it, as I need to edit the text that explain the steps too.

Comment: one bit more... non_zero = (x != 0) + 0;  xa = np.hstack([[0],non_zero,[0]]);
xadf = np.diff(xa); and then later vec2 = non_zero

Comment: @steve I was thinking the same after I made the edits that `xadf` does something similar. Let me edit it with these optimizations.

Comment: @steve The edits should cover those optimizations now.

Comment: @Divakar, By any chance can we make opposite of this solution? So running sum of zero values only?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and `np.hstack` :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([2.3, 1.2, 4.1 , 0.0, 0.0, 5.3, 0, 1.2, 3.1])
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> np.hstack([[i if j!=0 else j for i,j in enumerate(g,1)] for _,g in groupby(x,key=lambda x: x!=0)])
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  2.])
```

We can group the array elements based on non-zero elements then use a list comprehension and enumerate to replace the non-zero sub-arrays with those index then flatten the list with `np.hstack`.

Comment: As the other answer mentioned, this solution is slow for large inputs as it is pure-Python and not numpy-based.

Answer (score 0):

This sub-problem came up in [Kick Start](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart) 2021 Round A for me. My solution:

```py
def current_run_len(a):
    a_ = np.hstack([0, a != 0, 0])  # first in starts and last in stops defined
    d = np.diff(a_)
    starts = np.where(d == 1)[0]
    stops = np.where(d == -1)[0]
    a_[stops + 1] = -(stops - starts)  # +1 for behind-last
    return a_[1:-1].cumsum()
```

In fact, the problem also required a version where you count *down* consecutive sequences. Thus here another version with an optional keyword argument which does the same for `rev=False`:

```py
def current_run_len(a, rev=False):
    a_ = np.hstack([0, a != 0, 0])  # first in starts and last in stops defined
    d = np.diff(a_)
    starts = np.where(d == 1)[0]
    stops = np.where(d == -1)[0]
    if rev:
        a_[starts] = -(stops - starts)
        cs = -a_.cumsum()[:-2]
    else:
        a_[stops + 1] = -(stops - starts)  # +1 for behind-last
        cs = a_.cumsum()[1:-1]
    return cs
```

Results:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
print('a                             = ', a)
print('current_run_len(a)            = ', current_run_len(a))
print('current_run_len(a, rev=True)  = ', current_run_len(a, rev=True))
```

```
a                             =  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
current_run_len(a)            =  [1 2 3 4 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 0 1]
current_run_len(a, rev=True)  =  [4 3 2 1 0 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
```

For an array that consists of 0s and 1s only, you can simplify `[0, a != 0, 0]` to `[0, a, 0]`. But the version as-posted also works for arbitrary non-zero numbers.